# Algorithm for insert/sort into circular priority queue

Tags: java, algorithm, queue, priority-queue, circular-buffer

```
// gives next index in array which wraps around in a ring; moves clockwise through indices 
private int nextSlot(int k) { 
  return ((k + 1) % A.length); 
} 

// Insert method
public void insert(int k) {
   if( size == A.length)
       resize();
   A[next] = k;
   for(int i = 0; i < next; i = nextSlot(i)) {
       if(k < A[i]) {
           for( int j = next - 1; j >= i; j--){
               A[nextSlot(j)] = A[j];
           }
           A[i] = k;
           break;
       }
   }
   next = nextSlot(next);
   size++;
}
```

I am trying to create an insert/sort method that inserts values into a circular priority queue in ascending order. The problem I'm having is when the next pointer cycles back to the beginning of the array, the items at the front of the queue aren't being sorted. I've been struggling with this for hours now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, when *next* cycles back to the beginning, it's going to be 0, and therefore this for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < next; i = nextSlot(i)) {
```

will not do anything.

In general, however, I see several problems with your program.  First of all, why are you implementing this as a circular array?  Circular arrays are useful when you want to be able to quickly add/remove from both the beginning and end of an array.  You seem to be inserting into the middle, so there is no reason to complicate your code when you're doing a linear search through the entire list at each insert anyway.

Finally, be aware that when operating on a circular array, you need to take into account that your indices will wrap around and become 0.  Therefore, this line:

```
for( int j = next - 1; j >= i; j--)
```

is wrong for at least two reasons:

1. j>=i is not the correct way to find out if j has reached i
2. j-- is also wrong as j-1 needs to be wrapped

Comment: I'm trying to do this for a homework assignment that's why I'm implementing this as a circular array. I see what you're saying with the first for loop. When I modified it to 
    for(int i = 0; i <= next; i = nextSlot(i)) 
my program didn't throw any errors but didn't finish executing.
And for the second loop I changed j >= i to j == i and created a previousSlot method to wrap j in. When I run it with these changes nothing is sorted anymore.